# MVC4 Post Form with Image64

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post a generated image but not in ajax. The problem is that my param is set to null at server side.

Here is the action :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadImageDirect(string dataUrl)
    {
        var url = dataUrl.ToString().Substring(dataUrl.ToString().IndexOf(",") + 1);
        var image = Convert.FromBase64String(url);
        return base.File(image, "image/png", "pere_noel.png");
    }
```

Here is the form :

```
<form id="imgDownload" target="_blank" action="/Home/DownloadImageDirect" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="dataUrl" />
</form>
```

And here is the javascript :

```
yesButton.on('tap click', function () {
            var finalUrl = myKineticJSGroup.toDataURL({

                x: centerElem(rect.getWidth(), cadreImg).x,
                y: centerElem(rect.getHeight(), cadreImg).y,
                width: centerElem(rect.getWidth(), cadreImg).width,
                height: centerElem(rect.getHeight(), cadreImg).height,
            });

            $("#dataUrl").val(finalUrl);
            $("#imgDownload").submit();
        });
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC default data binding is done with **name attribute**, So give `<input type="hidden" id="dataUrl" />` a **name attribute** as shown below :-

```
<input type="hidden" id="dataUrl" name="dataUrl" />
```

and rest of your controller action code is fine.